# How to find xpath in below two html blocks?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How can I find out xpath in below 2 html blocks? Both html code are same, but only ID differs. Id is dynamic, so difficult to find xpath:

```
<div id="discoverytree-body" class="x-panel-body x-grid-body x-panel-body-default-framed x-panel-body-default-framed x-layout-fit" style="padding: 0px; border-top-width: 1px; width: 264px; left: 0px; height: 425px; top: 48px;">
   <div id="treeview-1015" class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default" tabindex="-1" style="margin: 0px; width: 262px; height: 423px;">
      <table class="x-grid-table x-grid-table-resizer" style="width:10000px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
         <tbody>
            <tr class="x-grid-header-row">
               <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-treecolumn-1014" style="width: 10000px; height: 0px;"/>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner" style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconDiscovery" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Discovery
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1349" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Common Settings
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1345" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Manage Components
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded x-grid-row-over">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconManagerDiscovery" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Manager Discovery
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td id="ext-gen1342" class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconSettings" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Settings
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused">
               <td id="ext-gen1384" class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1340" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     General
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td id="ext-gen1380" class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1336" class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Virtual Platforms
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1376" class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1332" class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Public Clouds
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1243" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1372" class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1239" class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Citrix NetScalers
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1247" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1368" class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1325" class="x-tree-elbow" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     vCloud Directors
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div id="ext-gen1251" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img id="ext-gen1321" class="x-tree-elbow-end" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Storage Discovery
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconActions" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Actions
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconAgentDiscovery" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Agent Discovery
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconSettings" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Settings
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-line" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     General
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-expanded">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end-plus x-tree-expander" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-parent iconActions" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Actions
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-tree-node-leaf">
               <td class="x-grid-cell-treecolumn x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-treecolumn-1014 x-grid-cell-first">
                  <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-empty" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-elbow-end" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     <img class="x-tree-icon x-tree-icon-leaf iconOU" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/>
                     Enable/Disable
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Above HTML is full page code, Here where I have to select the Discovery ->    Manager Discovery,       Actions->Enable/Disable

Xpath -

```
.//*[contains(text(), 'Manager Discovery')] //following::td[9]
```

Where `td[9]` denotes Actions->Enable/Disable and there is 1 matching node in UI.. but in code, no such element exception found. Tried with try catch block, JavaScript, Implicit and explicit wait, webdriver waits

Comment: Please paste full html code

Comment: So which button you want to click... first or second... if nothing else diffrenciated try with the index in xpath []... or store as a list and use index in your prog language

Comment: I want to click both buttons. But if I try to locate with this xpath, ".//*[contains(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(text(), 'Enable/Disable')]" Element not found exception displayed. But with fire path, 2 matching nodes are there. Needs to find out unique web element. Tried with index also, its not working

Comment: @ Aarya Pasted full html code oly

Comment: Can you format the HTML as per the original with the help of code snippet formatter? Additionally can you provide some more of the HTML DOM, before  and after <div id="ext-gen1225"> and <div id="ext-gen1246">

Comment: I have edited and pasted into html format

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to select? Both `div` and `td` contains `ext-gen` id, so it's unclear which exact element you need. Better to indicate whether `div` or `td` you are searching for easier future support (or use `classes` instead of `ids`, as they are different on these elements)

Also you have a lot of similar ids here, so better to use `starts-with()` instead of `contains()`.

```
(//div[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(.,'Enable/Disable')])[1]

(//div[starts-with(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(.,'Enable/Disable')])[2]

div could be replaced with td
```

**Some Explanation**:

`(locator)[n]` - searches nth element `among all found elements` by this locator

`locator[n]` - searches for `nth` element `by it's position in node.`

where:

> **n** = shortcut for `position()=n` and means position number. Could be
>   replaced with any integer 1,2,..,n , or any function that returns
>   integer
>
> **locator** = any element locator, like `//*[@id='someID']`

For example:

`(//*[@class='super'])[1]` - finds 1st element with class super among all elements on page
`//*[@class='super'][1]` - finds all elements with class super, which inside their nodes has position 1

so for html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="cell">1</td>
    <td class="cell">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">3</td>
    <td class="cell">4</td>
</tr>
```

Among all example: **(locator)[n]**

`(//td[@class='cell'])[2]` - returns 2nd element among all, so it's cell with value `'2'`

`(//td[@class='cell'])[3]` - returns 3rd element among all, so it's cell with value `'3'`

By position in node: **locator[n]**

`//td[@class='cell'][2]` - returns each 2nd cell in it's node, so it will return cells `'2' and '4'`

`//td[@class='cell'][3]` - returns nothing, as there is no 3rd cell in any node

**Here are XPATHes made after clarification in comments:**

```
//tr[contains(.,'Manager Discovery')]/following-sibling::tr[contains(.,'Enable/Disable')]
OR:
//tr[contains(.,'Manager Discovery')]/following-sibling::tr[16]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Let me try this above solution

Comment: I have tried the above, but still could not find unique xpath in UI. but for this xpath ".//*[contains(text(), 'Manager Discovery')] //following::td[9]"  1 matching node present in UI. but again no such element exception found

Comment: again, what you need to select? you provide invalid xpaths, but we still don't  know what result you expect

Comment: I have to select Enable/Disable. but provided xpath matching in UI. "//*[contains(text(), 'Manager Discovery')] //following::td[9]" , here td[9] denotes Enable/Disable

Comment: 1. //tr[contains(.,'Manager Discovery')]/following-sibling::tr[contains(.,'Enable/Disable')] - showing 2 matching nodes in UI    
2. //tr[contains(.,'Manager Discovery')]/following-sibling::tr[16] - 1 matching node in UI, but it is not selecting the Enable/Disable :(

Answer (score 0):

You can index like below

```
(.//*[contains(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(text(), 'Enable/Disable')])[1]
```

OR

```
(.//*[contains(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(text(), 'Enable/Disable')])[2]
```

Comment: Thank you! let me try and tell you

Comment: No Such element exception found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpaths:

For first element

```
//*[contains(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][1]
//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell-inner')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][1]
//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell-inner')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][1]
```

For second element

```
//*[contains(@id,'ext-gen')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][2]
//*[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell-inner')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][2]
//div[contains(@class,'x-grid-cell-inner')][contains(., 'Enable/Disable')][2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me try and tell you

Comment: No Such element exception found.

Comment: it is not possible strange, Put some wait and try

Comment: This is not correct, as it searches not for 1st/2nd node among all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the same case once. In order to click on both the buttons, you have to use 'Following-sibling' keyword. Means, you have to make relation between Parent and child so that there is unique relation. The provided html code is not enough to make relationship.

Comment: @Vivek Jolly, With Following syntax, found one Matching node in UI, ".//*[contains(text(), 'Manager Discovery')] //following::td[9]" but in code, 'no such element exception' found

Comment: @Vidhya: please write "following-sibling" instead of just "following" and before that put some wait also. let me know if that worked or not

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I didnt switch to iframe so that was the reason it didnt click on the element.